# Numbers loose their sign on conversion from double to short

Tags: c, type-conversion, fftw

I have been searching through the internet for several days to find a solution to the following problem.

In my program I am reading chunks of data from two 16 bit .wav files into sound buffers (arrays of type `short`) for which I allocate memory on the heap. The data is cast to `double` for the fftw functions and processed and then scaled down and cast to `short` to be placed into a collection buffer before writing the output file to disk. In this way I reduce the number of times I have to access the hard disk since I am reading several chunks of data (i.e. moving through the file) and don't want to write to disk in each iteration.

Here is what I am doing:

```
short* sound_buffer_zero;
short* sound_buffer_one;
short* collection_buffer_one;
sound_buffer_zero = (short *) fftw_malloc(sizeof(short) * BUFFERSIZE); 
sound_buffer_one = (short *) fftw_malloc(sizeof(short) * BUFFERSIZE);
collection_buffer_one = (short *) fftw_malloc(sizeof(short) * COLLECTIONLENGTH);

// read BUFFERSIZE samples from file into sound_buffer
inFileZero.read((char*)sound_buffer_zero, sizeof(short)*BUFFERSIZE);
inFileOne.read((char*)sound_buffer_one, sizeof(short)*BUFFERSIZE);

// typecast the short int values of sound_buffer into double values
// and write them to in_
for(int p = 0; p < BUFFERSIZE; ++p) {
    *(in_zero + p) = (double)*(sound_buffer_zero + p);
    *(in_one + p) = (double)*(sound_buffer_one + p);
}

// cross correlation in the frequency domain
// FFT on input zero (output is f_zero)
fftw_execute(p_zero);

// FFT on input one (output is f_one)
fftw_execute(p_one);

// complex multiplication (output is almost_one, also array of type double)
fastCplxConjProd(almost_one, f_zero, f_one, COMPLEXLENGTH);

// IFFT on almost_one (output is out_one, array of double)
fftw_execute(pi_one);

// finalize the output array (sort the parts correctly, output is final_one, array of double)
// last half without first value becomes first half of final array
for(int i = ARRAYLENGTH/2 + 1; i < ARRAYLENGTH; ++i) {
    *(final_one + i - (ARRAYLENGTH/2 + 1)) = *(out_one + i);
}
// first half becomes second half of final array
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH/2; ++i) {
    *(final_one + i + (ARRAYLENGTH/2 - 1)) = *(out_one + i);
}

short* scaling_vector; 
scaling_vector = (short *) fftw_malloc(sizeof(short) * ARRAYLENGTH-1);

// fill the scaling_vector with the numbers from 1, 2, 3, ..., BUFFERSIZE, ..., 3, 2, 1
for(short i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE; ++i) {
    *(scaling_vector + i) = i + 1;
    if(i + BUFFERSIZE > ARRAYLENGTH-1) break;
    *(scaling_vector + i + BUFFERSIZE) = BUFFERSIZE - i - 1;
}

// scale values in relation to their position in the output array
// to values suitable for short int for storage
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH-1; ++i) {
    *(final_one + i) = *(final_one + i) * SCALEFACTOR; // #define SCALEFACTOR SHRT_MAX/pow(2,42)
    *(final_one + i) = *(final_one + i) / *(scaling_vector + i);
}

// transform the double values of final_ into rounded short int values
// and write them to the collection buffer
for(int p = 0; p < ARRAYLENGTH-1; ++p) {
    *(collection_buffer_one + collectioncount*(ARRAYLENGTH) + p) = (short)round(*(final_one + p));
}

// write collection_buffer to disk
 outFileOne.write((char*)collection_buffer_one, sizeof(short)*collectioncount*(ARRAYLENGTH));
```

The values that are computed in the cross-correlation are of type `double` and have positive or negative signs. By scaling them down, the sign does not change. But when I cast them to `short` the numbers that arrive in the collection_array are all positive.

The array is declared as `short`, not as `unsigned short`, and after scaling the values are in a range that `short` can hold (you have to trust me on this one, because I don't want to post *all* my code to keep the post readable). I don't care about the truncation of the decimal part, I don't need that for further computation, but the signs should stay the same.

Here is a little example for the input and output values (shown are the first 10 values in the arrays):

```
input: 157
input: 4058
input: -1526
input: 1444
input: -774
input: -1507
input: -1615
input: -1895
input: -987
input: -1729

// converted to double
as double: 157
as double: 4058
as double: -1526
as double: 1444
as double: -774
as double: -1507
as double: -1615
as double: -1895
as double: -987
as double: -1729

// after the computations 
after scaling: -2.99445
after scaling: -42.6612
after scaling: -57.0962
after scaling: 41.0415
after scaling: -18.3168
after scaling: 43.5853
after scaling: -14.3663
after scaling: -3.58456
after scaling: -46.3902
after scaling: 16.0804

// in the collection array and before writing to disk
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 3
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 43
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 57
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 41
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 18
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 44
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 14
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 4
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 46
collection [short(round*(final_one))]: 16
```

My question is, why are the signs not retained? Am I missing some internal conversion? I did not find an answer to my question in the other posts. If I missed it, please let me know and also If I left out important info for you. Thanks for your help!

Cheers, 
mango

Here's the code for the test ouputs:

```
//contents of sound_buffer (input from file):
// test output
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cout << "input: " << *(sound_buffer_zero + i) << endl;
}

// content of in_ after converting to double
// test output
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cout << "as double: " << *(in_zero + i) << endl;
}

// contents of final_ after the scaling
// test output 
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cout << "after scaling: " << *(final_one + i) << endl;
}

// contents of collection_buffer after converting to short
// test output
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cout << "collection [short(round*(final_one))]: " << *(collection_buffer_one + i) << endl;
}
```

Thanks to *aleguna* I found that the signs vanish in the following computations. I had totally missed that step where I do `final_one = fabs(final_one)`. I had put that in for a test and totally forgotten about it.

Thank you all for your comments and answers. It turns out, I was just stupid. I am sorry.

Comment: If I understood it right, I replaced `round` with `lrint` (since I pass `double` values to it) and try again. Same results. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: what is collectioncount*(ARRAYLENGTH) ? Why don't you use the `ptr[offset]` notation, which is simpler to understand, rather than the `*(ptr + offset)` notation?

Comment: @didierc I am quite comfortable with the `*(ptr + offset)` notation, reading it as `"value(at this address)"` Apart from readability for some, does it make a functional difference? If so, I am willing to change it. The collectioncount tells where in the collection_buffer array to start writing the values of the next iteration. As I mentioned above, I am iterating through files and collecting the results of several iterations before writing to disk.

Comment: I don't see this behavior on my short test program. Could you post a small, self-contained compilable example exhibiting the problem for a single number?

Comment: You didn't give informations about how `collectioncount` behaves outside the provided code. Does it matter?

Comment: I really wish you had chosen to use array indexing instead of pointer arithmetic...

Comment: Just to sanity check your compiler, could you try to change the type to `signed short` at this location only: `(signed short)round(*(final_one + p));`. If the code suddenly works after that, then you are using some non-standard compiler setting for integer signedness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform are you running this on? 
I did a little test on linux x86, gcc 3.4.2

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <math.h>

   int main (int,  char*[])
   {
       double a = -2.99445;
       short b = (short)round(a);

       std::cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << std::endl;
      return 0;
   }
```

output

```
a = -2.99445 b = -3
```

So I can think of two scenarios

1. You haven't shown us some code between scaling and converting to short
2. You run some exotic platform with non-standard double representation

Comment: I am using WinXP 32bit. The code is written and run for tests in NetBeans 7.1.2 with g++ in MinGW. I did the same test and came to the same results as you. I just compiled your code here and yield the same result again. That's why I am at a loss with the code above. There are no more computations or permutations between the scaling and the conversion.

Comment: @bat-mango, please show the code which prints out the values

Comment: I edited my original post above and provided the loops that print out the contents of the arrays at each step.

Comment: @bat.mango, in the loop where you cast to short add a test out put, smth like `cout << "Before ": << *(final_one + p) << " After: "<< (short)round(*(final_one + p)) << endl;`

Comment: @ aleguna, thanks for the tipp. That made me recognize that the signs were already missing before casting the values to short. And I have to admit that there are indeed two more computations which I did not expect to alter the values. I see now, where I went wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: @bat.mango Lesson learnt: post the real code :)

Comment: @Lundin lesson definitely learned.

Answer (score 0):

How does the following run on your platform, when compiled with no optimization at all?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double a[10] = { 
  -2.99445,
  -42.6612,
  -57.0962,
  41.0415,
  -18.3168,
  43.5853,
  -14.3663,
  -3.58456,
  -46.3902,
  16.0804
};

int main(){
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<10;++i){
    short k = (short)*(a + i);
    printf("%d\n", k);
  }

}
```

gives me the following results:

```
-2
-42
-57
41
-18
43
-14
-3
-46
16
```

Comment: I added my results to your answer, not yet visible, but they are -2, -42, -57, 41, -18, 43, -14, -3, -46, 16. Signs stay as they are. Why not in my conversion above?

Comment: Ok, obviously your compiler works ok with double to short conversions. So the problem is elsewhere. What about `collectioncount`?

Comment: Yes, the problem was a line of code in a subroutine that originally should not alter any values. I had put that line in for a test and then forgotten about it. I already learned my lesson. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @bat.mango: sure, no problem. Don't forget to close the question!

Comment: can't. not enough reputation I guess. Or how do I do that? I joined only recently.

Comment: Ok, I cannot either, but I assumed that people who started a topic could close it.

Answer (score -2):

Normally, short is 2-byte long while double is 8-byte long. Casting double to short causes the loss of the upper bytes. Even if 2 bytes is enough for your actual data without the sign, you'll loose the sign info which is stored in the upper bytes by sign extending.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you give me a clue where I can read more on the internal going-ons during type conversions? So I don't make these mistakes again... Thank you!

Comment: You can start from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension

Comment: This is not correct - he is not casting via pointers - he's just casting the double result of round to a short, which should be fine *so long as the value is not outside the range of a short*.

Comment: When a floating-point value is converted to an integral type, the sign is retained, so this is not what's going on here.

Comment: @icepack Thanks. I am really just beginning to understand this.

Comment: @PaulR That's what I said, you just rephrased it.

Comment: @PaulR The values _are_ not outside the range of a short, aren't they? So what is causing the sign to vanish?

Comment: @ecatmur May I ask for the source of such knowledge?

Comment: @icepack **6.3.1.4 Conversions (Arithmetic operations) (Real floating and integer)** in the C standard, paragraph 1.  You can read a draft of the standard at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf.

Comment: @icepack: sorry - on re-reading I can see now that this is what you were trying to say, but the answer is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @ecatmur Don't see anything about sign retaining there

Comment: @icepack no, because it's implied that if the result is representable in the destination type that value will be stored.

Comment: @ecatmur that's trivial if the data is inside the range of target type. Try casting -128 into signed char. Truncation will result in loss of sign besides the loss of absolute value. If it wasn't clear, that's exactly what I meant.